# create and compile "hello world" application in Linux using Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am new to Linux, but developed C/C++ in windows for some times now.

I installed a Linux Ubuntu 16.4 and Visual Studio Code.

I create a folder and inside that folder I created a file called main.cpp and inside that file I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
void main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

Now I want to compile and run it and possibly debug it (step by step to see how I can debug a simple application).

How can I do this?

Any tutorial on to setup a development system in Linux using Visual Studio Code?

I installed "C/C++ for Visual Studio Code" but I am still not able to compile and run the sample application.

## Edit1

I already installed compiler and can compile my code using

```
g++ main.cpp
```

and getting a.out

How can I configure VSC to automate this processor and generate dependency and if there is an error, open the file with error on editor and show me the line that generate error. Also during debug show me the source code when I am stepping the code.

These are some basic requirement that I have from a development system, otherwise I call it an editor and not a development system.

Comment: VS Code is an editor. You need a compiler.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I think Linux comes with GCC and compiler and it is already installed, so my question is how to configure VSC to use the compiler and build my application? Should I create a makefile? can VSC generate the make file for me, or I should do it by myself? If I need to do it by myself, how I can configure VSC to run the make and then attach to application to be able to debug it?

Comment: You system has a compiler called g++. You C++ code is invalid due to missing return type for `main` (in old C there was implicit int feature, not in C++). Just compile from the command line.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use VS Code?

Comment: @NeilButterworth To make development and debugging easier. I used VS on windows a lot and I like it as a development system. I can use a makefile to build my system, but I want to use VSC as I think it would make my development easier.

Comment: "I think Linux comes with GCC and compiler " Might do, might not - depends entirely on what distribution you are using. Some don't come witha C or C++ compiler, some come with just a C compiler, and some with both.

Comment: @NeilButterworth My system has g++, as I can manually compile the code using g++ main.cpp and it generates a.out. My question is how to configure VSC to develop c/c++ code in Linux?

Comment: Please consider a real IDE, such as Eclipse with CDT, NetBeans, CLion, or others, if you only have VS experience in the past. I don't expect you pick up all the command line based tooling quickly and then use tasks.json to wire them up.

Answer (score -1):

First, you have to install a compiler, I recommend GCC (Ubuntu usually doesn't come with one even though it's mostly written in C/C++)

Second, compile your program, here's how

> To compile the program, open the terminal and move on to the target directory type the command – (where gcc implies compiler name, then it asks for the file name of the source program while -o option specifies the file name of the output program)
>
> ```
> gcc hello.c -o hello1
> ```
>
> If there is no syntax/semantic error in you program then the compiler will successfully generate an executable file, otherwise fix the problem in your code.

However, that will only work for C, here's how to do it for C++ (only if the extension is .cpp)

> The steps are almost same as above but you need to install g++ compiler, the file extension should be .cpp and in compilation phase replace gcc with g++. To install G++ compiler, execute the command -

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

The compilation command now is:

```
g++ hello.cpp -o hello1
```

It goes without saying that you should replace "hello.cpp" with your files name and "hello1" with the name you want your "exe" file to have